# APA 6th referencing

Tags: apa6

I need to use APA 6e referencing for Elsevier Journal, Here is the code, I don't know why I encounter errors. I'm not using `\documentclass{apa6e}` as I need to retain format of Elsevier article.

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\journal{Expert Systems with Applications}

\begin{document}
\title{Recurrent neural network and a hybrid model for prediction of stock returns}


\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\bibliography{myrefers}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The errors are caused by the fact that `elsarticle` loads the `natbib` package unconditionally, and this is incompatible with `apacite.sty`.  A minimal document demonstrating this is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{apacite}

\begin{document}

Ouch!

\end{document}
```

which produces the same error

> ```
> ! Undefined control sequence.
> l.1216           \st@rtbibchapter
> ```

as in your situation.

A small example correctly using citations in `elsarticle` would be:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}

\journal{Expert Systems with Applications}

\begin{document}
\title{Recurrent neural network and a hybrid model for prediction of stock returns}

\cite{article-full}

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num-names}

\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]

Comment: I have the same problem. I was instructed by the same journal: ``APA's in-text citations require the author's last name and the year of publication. You should cite publications in the text, for example, (Smith, 2016).`` I have managed to produce in text references but they are in the format ``Smith, (2016)`` whereas according to the guidelines I need them to be ``(Smith, 2016)``. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: @StuckInPhD Just use `\citep` instead of `\cite`, see the `natbib` documentation.